# How 'New' is a Blog Post?

Tags: support, blog, footer

I see a [image: new] [image: new] icon next to 'blog' in the footer.  I was wondering how [image: new] a post has to be for that to remain.  I have viewed the post many times, and the icon has not gone away, so I assume it is not tied to a person't account.

I was just wondering how [image: new] is [image: new]?  (Or, when will [image: new] go away?)

Comment: Was there supposed to be a picture in between `a` and `icon`? I don't see anything

Comment: @TheLQ It should read "I see a new new icon" It's odd that you don't see that.

Comment: Nevermind, my stupid websense firewall is blocking *.imgur.com as "Personal Network Storage and Backup" (school, not corporate)

Comment: @TheLQ, there are 6 instances of the image taking the place of the word 'new' in hte post.  So it may be difficult to read, sorry.

Comment: @TheLQ, is the alt text not appearing either?

Comment: @Michael No, because Firefox is treating the block page as an image, not text. It's thinking its a 2x1 GIF. I'm not sure if there's anything that can be done about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new indicator will go away if there isn't a new blog post on the blog for 24 hours.

Comment: Shouldn't the new indicator go away on reading the blog post? I've seen the same post twice now thinking it was new.

Answer (score 0):

Hover your mouse over the "new" and you'll see a tooltip.

For me now (15:20 GMT 4th Jan 2011) it reads "10 hours ago".

So that's how "new" "new" is.

When will it go away? I don't know yet.

Comment: I saw the tooltip, and it reads 10 hours ago now.  But I wouldn't consider that new anymore....oh well.

Comment: Oh, sweet! But I misunderstood this as "new: The blog feature". This should read "new posts" or "updated" instead