# chat link removed from navigation bar at the top?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! Where did the chat top navigation link go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go)

The navigation bar has no *chat* link anymore, if there is a new blog post.

Crypto Stack Exchange:
[image]

Meta:
[image]

Stack Overflow:
[image]

For comparison, if there is no new blog post (like now at tex.stackexchange - they have a separate blog), the chat link still is there:
[image]

I suppose this is to avoid a too crowded navigation bar, but it is annoying for me. (I know there is a *chat* link with same functionality at the bottom, but I don't want to have to scroll down for this.)

A week ago (when the last blog posts appeared) the navigation bar had still enough place for both blog and chat link, if I remember correct.

Comment: Ah, the duplicate did not have the [meta-tag:chat] tag, thus I didn't find it. Thanks.