# Always show chat and blog link in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, top-bar

It's [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101464/157047) [addressed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101504/157047), the "chat" link which either shows up or doesn't show up in the top bar is confusing. (hardly surprising)

I suggest the following:

- Always show the "chat" link.
- Always show the "blog" link (when the SE site has a blog).
- Highlight the blog link instead of putting "new" in front of it when there is a new blog post.

Result:

- No more "shifting" GUI parts. (If this were to be a reason for the current design, ironically it does shift now due to the "new" icon.)
- It's always visible whether or not a site has a blog.
- Users aren't surprised. When they use the link once, they can always find it again.

As a side note: the "new" icon in front of the bottom "blog" link doesn't disappear along with the one in the top-bar after clicking on the link.

---

To prevent any further "but, you can find the link in so many other places"-answers:

> It's not an issue whether it's hard to find. The issue is it's
>   inconsistent and confusing. I learned I was able to find it there, and
>   afterwards it's no longer there ... that's the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eeeek! Where did the chat top navigation link go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go) and thanks for making it so easy  to find the dupe ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException: This is a feature request. I don't see the suggestion in your mentioned duplicate. (I actually link to it.)

Comment: I consider it essentially a duplicate because Jeff himself basically said this is [meta-tag:status-bydesign] on the very question you linked to. But we'll se if 4 other people agree with me!

Comment: Well, this is a [tag:feature-request], asking to reconsider the [tag:status-bydesign]. ;p

Comment: Good luck with that Steven, I haven't seen many succeed on that quest! ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I really don't think this is necessary.

Chat is **not hard to find**. It's always at `http://chat.<sitename>.com` And there's plenty of other links to it.

[As Jeff himself says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101470/131541):

> You can also find chat links, at least on any *meta*, on every
>   question page in the sidebar:
>
> [image]
>
> Note that "4 people chatting" is a link to the rooms page, whereas the
>   rooms are.. links to the individual rooms.

And it's at the bottom, [as Reno points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101466/131541):

> [image: Right here!]
>
> You will find it on the footer navigation bar thingy.
>
> ----  On Chrome/Firefox - hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the bottom.

Comment: I that case, _never_ put it in the top link. It's not an issue whether it's hard to find. The issue is it's inconsistent and confusing. I learned I was able to find it there, and afterwards it's no longer there ... that's the problem.

Comment: Well, we disagree that it's confusing then -- that's okay! :-)