# Chat side-bar not showing up on Server Fault

Tags: support, chat

As Jeff has pointed out (to some controversy), when a new blog post is made the blog link temporarily replaces the chat link in the top navigation bar. He also points out (with a copious amount of arrows) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go/101470#101470), that most SE sited have a chat box thingy on the right hand side. Unfortunately, Server Fault does not have this chat box on the right hand side.

From top to bottom, I see the "Do you haz teh codez" ad, the Careers 2.0 ad, the tag cloud, and the recently awarded badges. If you're going to remove the link from the top, can you please make sure that the side bar thingamabobber is working?

Comment: *"with a copious amount of arrows"* Right? And they weren't even freehand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serverfault does have this; but as with all right-hand panels, it is on rotation. It also only shows within *questions* (not the home page, AFAIK). It might take a few loads, but is definitely there.

[image]

Comment: I can see you guys aren't going to budge on this, but will you at least admit that replacing a chat link with a blog link once in a while is just kinda...weird?

Comment: @MarkM budge on what? the main thrust of the question seems to be the sidebar. The sidebar is there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the blog link replacing the chat link. Since the sidebar isn't available with any regularity, when there's a blog post the only guaranteed way that a new user can get to chat is the footer, which they'll likely miss.

Comment: I've tried reloading 10 times on a question page in English Language and Usage, but chat does not appear in the side bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's also linked on the bottom in the footer, so scroll down on your page.

And it is linked on meta in the sidebar.

Comment: Does this mean that you're giving up on pushing chat? I know it's pretty popular on SF. Comms Room usually has 10-15 active chatters and it's developed a pretty good community. A lot of us feel that replacing the chat link every time there's a blog post makes no sense. We love it when a new knowledgeable/fun person becomes a regular chatter, but thinking that any newer member would notice it in the footer or go to a meta and notice it is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: um, no? it just means the blog link at the top of the page supercedes chat for 24 hours.

Comment: I know that it's only for 24 hours, but it just seems really unintuitive and plain weird that one link gets replaced with another totally unrelated link at random intervals.