# When is the RHS chat box shown?

Tags: support, chat

There's sometimes a RHS box advertising for chat - the one with avatars of people recently in chat and so on. After plenty of time using the site, I have absolutely no idea how it decides whether to appear. Given the frequency I do see it, I'm not sure if newer users are likely to notice it. (And we do want them to see it on Seasoned Advice - it's a good place to get an answer to the more vague, subjective questions we have to close.)

So: when does it appear? Is it consistent enough that new users might discover it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101898/chat-side-bar-not-showing-up-on-server-fault/102398#102398

Comment: @random thanks - I think the box (with colorful avatars) is a lot more eye-catching than a tiny bottom link, and a lot more likely to be seen on main than meta, though.

Comment: And to clarify: the *other* answer on that question says it's "on rotation" and it might take "a few loads" but I often don't see it at all, after dozens of loads. I'm trying to ask what the actual behavior is.