# Unifying the main site/chat/meta/blog links in the header

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, top-bar

When chat was first introduced, it was referred to as a "third place". Now, we have what is essentially a fourth place: The [site blogs](http://blogoverflow.com/). (Yes, it's on a wordpress engine, and not all sites have them, but many do. But it's a component of a site's presence.) If this trend continues, there will eventually be a fifth place, and a sixth place, and so on.

Perhaps, before this goes any further, it's time to re-examine the way SE addresses iterations of the sites, from an interface standpoint.

I suggest that, instead of the **chat** link that's at the top of all sites (which sometimes, confusingly enough, becomes the **blog** link, but [that's another discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go)) with a drop-down menu. This would be populated by links to chat, meta, the SE blog, as well as the *site* blog (if there is one) - and, also, any future sites introduced on a network-wide basis.

[image]

Integrating the site blogs into the SE system more tightly would also allow for the blog icon to indicate when there's a new post on the site blog and/or for the main SE blog. (Would a tie-in to blogoverflow do the trick?)

While introducing a new drop-down menu complicates the interface a little, it's simpler than pushing stuff to the footer, which - I think - few people look at regularly.

So - am I on the right track, or would this be a horribly well-intentioned idea? Is this already being considered in some form or another?

Comment: +1. Pretty sure waffles/Sam and Jeff have been unhappy with the header at various points lately, so hopefully they're considering *something*.

Comment: Not sure I'd be happier with a drop down though...

Comment: I don't use the chat or blog links, so I don't care what happens to them, but please don't bury meta in a dropdown; I use that constantly

Comment: @Benjoi - I'd love to hear a better option, but I can't think of one. Any ideas? (Other than turning the header into a win3.1-style nightmare of a gazillion links, of course.) Maybe integrate this into the SuperColliding Dropdown thingamabob menu?

Comment: I don't remember Windows 3.1 having any links at all.

Comment: @Cody - Use your imagination! Think "crowded UI".

Comment: Hmm, I remember Windows 3.1 fondly as having an excellent, totally non-cluttered UI. It definitely didn't have many "drop-downs" to hide things. I'm not really convinced that's an improvement.

Comment: @Cody - We must have been using a different win3.1, then.

Comment: Have added a mockup image. It'd be nice if this got some attention. It hasn't even gotten a status-rejected tag.

Comment: This is pretty much implemented now with the new top bar. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit more complicated that what you suggested, but the [new top bar](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/) does have a dropdown menu unification thingy:

[image: Meta, chat, blog, and log out in one place.]

Enjoy!

Comment: Man you surely aged quickly... hope it isn't because of the stress at work! :D

Comment: By the way, missing free hand red circles here. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I just turned forty and I don't have time for drawing circles.  But since you asked...

Comment: Hey, this isn't your account in the screenshot to the right. Who's account did you use for the screenshot?

Comment: @hichris123 this is [David's account](http://stackexchange.com/users/32917/david-fullerton?tab=accounts) - coworker (or boss?) of Jon here. :)