# Stop replacing "Chat" with "Blog" every time you blog something new

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! Where did the chat top navigation link go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go)

I go to a site, I want to find the chatroom, so there's this button I like to click called "chat", but for some reason we've deceived that every time we have a new blog post, we need to remove the way I get to the chat room-- and I don't remember the crazy URL scheme for the various SE sites to get into the chatroom, but the regulars do.

[image]

**Why are new blog posting stopping me from getting to the chat room?**

Infinite rage.

... After searching the page for "chat," it turns out there's a link in the side column, which is cool, except I've been trained to look here, not there.

Basically, I'm asking for something very simple: don't replace buttons because you have a new blog post. Do anything except replace it. That's where I've become accustomed to look for it, and it's really confusing. It's there one day, poof, gone the next, then it's back, now it's gone. Are ya feeling luck today?

Comment: I'm not opposed to this, but it's also linked on the bottom, and the "crazy url scheme" is chat.stackexchange.com; just bookmark it

Comment: Unfortunately, http://chat.stackexchange.com/ and http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=security.stackexchange.com are two different things. It seems to be based on what website you send an HTTP refer from...

Comment: Sure, but you can also just go to the homepage, click the "site" tab, and click "(more sites...)" to let you choose one

Comment: The duplicate isn't a duplicate at all; that asking _why_, this is begging _stop!_ The OP obviously already knows _why_ it is happening and is making a request for this craziness to be corrected.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek That doesn't resolve broken usability.

Comment: @Incognito I'm not going to argue usability, I already said changing it back would be fine with me. I don't think it's going to get changed, so I'm telling you how to deal with it

Comment: if that change is "stopping" you from getting to the chat room, you aren't trying very hard. chat is linked in the footer, and on the sidebar of every question with 4 or more answers (it may randomly appear on questions with >= 1 answers)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood I'm not worried about the veritable cornucopia of paths we have to get to chat, I just don't see the sense in automatically bricking off a common doorway to the kitchen and putting a fireplace into a spot that's always been a door to the kitchen, then ripping out the fire place after 24 hours, putting the door back, and waiting quietly in the dark for the next time to strike with such a fiendish plot. We do this because we put a new log on the fire. I full well grasp the detailed diagram you drafted a few weeks back, I really *really* do, but finding a link isn't the issue.

Comment: so.. we moved your cheese, then? :)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood Well, at least I know what to expect on April fools. http://jsfiddle.net/TH5hK/embedded/result/

Comment: @Incognito: You don't have to wait until April Fools. Just try using the auto-inflating search box, live on the sites for the past week or so. Both are equally as maddening. Jeff apparently has a compulsion about keeping the number of items in the top navbar to an absolute minimum. But that presents quite a conflict with his desire to promote the blog, widen the search box, add new features, etc.