# Don't replace the Chat link with the New Blog link in the header; truncate (...) long usernames

Tags: feature-request

The reasoning for not including *both* the Chat and Blog links in the `#hlinks` DIV is a bit silly.

> @kyle people with long names would wrap – Jeff Atwood♦ Aug 10 at 1:46
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101470/172108

If the problem is long usernames, why don't we just truncate them temporarily?

[image: Long Username]

Comment: Makes sense. They already do this for the usernames in the grey box in the bottom right corner of posts (except without the `...`).

Comment: This is a duplicate (searching....)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101464/155556

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Not a duplicate. They asked where it went, or why it gets replaced. My post is specifically a feature request. Plus, that is where I got my quote from.