# Can we put blog notifications on the Community Bulletin Board instead of the header?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, community-bulletin

I want to request a change to the title bar design site wide.

I don't particularly like when blog replaces the chat in the main line up to the left of the search field. It makes it hard to leave a comment anywhere like "I'd love to move this conversation to chat - use the link at the top of every page" and then have the OP read that on the day when blog is there.

I love the new community bulletin board area where we can feature meta posts, events and blog entries better than before with the red circle and blog taking the place of chat in the title bar.

Could you revisit this design decision now that we have a very nice tool for announcements?

If you feel keeping blog instead of chat in the title bar, would you at least put a link to the main chat room as the first entry in the bulletin board at the same time as chat is missing from the title?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eeeek! Where did the chat top navigation link go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go)... +1 though, as excited as I am to read the new blog post, I'd like to easily get back to chat as well :)

Comment: @lix I don't think this is a dupe at all. It's asking for a change in established behavior.

Comment: @Lix: There was no bulletin board back when that was asked.

Comment: Any one of those answers could answer this question as well... For me, that's a duplicate... A change is not really needed becuase *where ever you are* a link to chat is not far away...  If you didn't notice **I support this request...** I hope it goes through.

Comment: I'm looking to deprecate the "eek" factor that results from removing the chat link at random 24 hour intervals that correspond with a recent blog emission.

Comment: YES!! Please!!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an excellent idea - the changing header links are quite annoying.

With the bulletin board now available everywhere, Emmett was able to make this happen.

Comment: Just fabulous. Thanks to Emmett and others for making this change so quickly.