# How can we improve the visibility of new blog posts?

Tags: discussion, blog

On the main site of [SeasonedAdvise](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), I've missed a number of blog posts when they appeared (and I'm a regular customer). That's because the link to the blog is way under the fold.

I'd like to be aware of new blog posts, so how can I get that?

1. Put the 'blog' link in the top navigation bar. This will probably not happen as the top navigation bar contents has been frozen.
2. Show a 'new blog' icon next to the logo.
3. Show a 'new blog' link in the [community bulletin*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132146/can-we-put-blog-notifications-on-the-community-bulletin-board-instead-of-the-hea). Maybe this already happens but if so, it should be a different colour as I (mea culpa) tend to ignore the bulletin.
4. Create an 'opt-in' for new blog post notifications.
5. Reproduce the MSO behaviour. Show a 'new blog' in the top navigation bar only when it happens.

I'd like to discuss which solution would be best, before creating the corresponding [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

**Edit:** * Just saw the number 3 [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) has been implemented. As I've missed these notifications, maybe they should be in a different colour (repeating myself).