# How to make the "new" for the blog go away - right now?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the New blog message disappear after reading it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101315/make-the-new-blog-message-disappear-after-reading-it)

A new blog post has been added today, and the "new" tag is driving me crazy. I'm *so* used to the scheme "red thingy on top of SO - your attention is needed!" that I just can't look away.

It has already been asked when it will go away on its own, see [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73879/151019). What I'd like to know however is: how can I make it disappear **right now**?

If I can't make it go away - can you please implement means to make it go away?

It's just itching me so much I feel I can't visit SO until I got rid of it. I even considered sticking a piece of a post-it on the screen to cover it up.

Help. Please!

Comment: Mind telling me of which question this is supposed to be a duplicate? The one I mentioned asks when it will go away *on its own*, I'm requesting a feature to dismiss it manually though. Isn't that something completely different?

Comment: I guess you squashed it with your edit, but since it was presumably inside the 5min window we can't see it. Anyway, I assume the duplicate is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101315/make-the-new-blog-message-disappear-after-reading-it

Comment: I assume this is a carefully-crafted joke, since nobody could possibly be that itchy about a little red icon on a form. I'm married, so believe me, things like this don't even hit my radar.

Comment: well it _is_ a tad annoying @Robert given the close proximity to the other alerts for the mods...

Comment: I'm married as well. I'm even proud father to a little son, age six months. Maybe that's why the icon is itching me so much - I've learnt to quickly get rid of tiny, annoying things which are just lying around, before they end up in my sons mouth.

Comment: DMA57361 is right about the duplicate, though.

Comment: So when can we get the chat link back?